# how can i print the username of the user who login using session

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

This is my Users model

```
public function user_login($email, $password)
{
    $this->load->library('session');
    $this->db->where('email', $email);
    $this->db->where('password', $password);
    $query = $this->db->get('users');
    if($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach($query->result() as $row) {
            $data = array(
                'id' => $row->id,
                'username' => $row->username,
                'email' => $row->email
            );
            $this->session->set_userdata($data);
        }
        return 1;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

On my view i have a div to display the session username of the user

```
<div>
    <?php echo $this->session->userdata('username'); ?>
</div>
```

It's does not appear What could be wrong?

---

When I print the contents of `userdata()` like this

```
<?php print_r($this->session->userdata()); ?>
```

I get the response

```
Array ( [__ci_last_regenerate] => 1502894606 )
```

Comment: What is your output if you do `<?php print_r($this->session->userdata()); ?>`?

Comment: check the session data $this->session->has_userdata('username'); Also  initialize the Session class manually in your controller.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Array ( [__ci_last_regenerate] => 1502894606 ) 1 thats what i get when i print_r

Comment: @raving Reddy i loaded the library session il try has_userdata

Comment: **Never store plain text passwords!** Please use **PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html)** (`password_hash()` and `password_verify()`)to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat). **It is not necessary** to [escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527) or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so _changes_ the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: It looks like your session data is not being set for some reason.

Comment: That's what i thought is there any other way to set a session other than the way i used to write it

Comment: @Lestah I'm not familiar enough with codeigniter to help you unfortunately. From the docs it looks ike you are doing it correctly.

Comment: Why you do not try to send instead of `$data` just one atributte **username** for example?

Answer (score 0):

simplify your query some

```
$data = $this->db->where(['email'=>$email, 'password'=>$password])->get('users')->row_array();
if($data){
    $_SESSION['id'] = $data['id'];
    $_SESSION['username'] = $data['username'];
    $_SESSION['email'] = $data['email'];
    return TRUE;
}
else{
   return FALSE;
}
```

in view:

```
<div>
     <?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

try to print it out like this `echo $data['username']` where `$data` is whatever variable you are sending to the view from the controller

Answer (score -1):

If you actually have a username at line with

```
$row->username
```

Then right after that array, add

```
$this->load->vars( array('username' => $row->username) );
```

And in your view you would be able to get username

```
echo $username;
```

This is assuming you are not redirecting after setting your session.

Comment: I'm sure OP wants to use the variable again in other views, hence using sessions.

Comment: I never said not to use sessions. I just said this is a way to get the username to the view immediately. No part of what I said recommended removal of existing code.

Comment: Then this does not answer the question.

Comment: Here you are babbling about sessions not being set for some reason, and you think I'm wrong about this? You admit that you're not familiar with CodeIgniter, but I'm wrong? ... and you downvote me?

Comment: I also didn't post an answer that doesn't attempt to solve the issue. I never said you were wrong, I said your answer doesn't answer the question, therefore it's "not useful" as the downvote tooltip says.

Comment: And there's no way you could, because you don't know what you're doing.

Comment: Exactly why I didn't :) However, if you "know what you are doing" more than me, you can attempt to actually answer the question and I will retract my vote. Just because I don't know about codeigniter (As I have never personally used it), does not make my downvote less valid.